# Errors were encountered while processing python-mysqldb

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I am getting error when I run `apt-get -f install` .... error is

> "Errors were encountered while processing:  python-mysqldb E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but nothing works.[image: THIS IS WHAT I AM GETTING]

Is this is due to corrupted re.py file as I messed up with that a day ago while installing openstack?

Comment: Sounds like a plausible explanation then.  Please don't post text as screen shots.

Comment: Yes, apt is trying to complete the installation and failing. Search on Ask Ubuntu how to repair the apt issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you have backed up that file, restore it, otherwise uninstall python2.7 and re-install it